# Group django formset into groups based on foreign key

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple setup of InventoryItems and Categories.  I have a formset of InventoryItems but want to split up the items based on the FK Category, I don't need or want an inline form set.

Simplified version of what I have

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    inventory = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Inventory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

def viewOfForm(request):
    categories = Category.objects.filter(inventory=True)
    InventoryFormset = modelformset_factory(Inventory, can_delete=True, extra=1)
    formset = InventoryFormset(request.POST or None, queryset=Inventory.objects.filter(category__inventory=True))
    return render_to_response('template.html', locals())
```

What I would like to do in the template

```
{% for category in categories %}
<fieldset class="collapse">
<h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>
{% for form in formset %}
{% if form.category == category %}
{{ form }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need a small change to get this working; use `form.instance.category` in your `if` template tag:

```
{% if form.instance.category == category %}
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed the ability to use form.instance before.  Thanks.